# How to represent a document in test data with the Document-Term Matrix created from the training set?

Tags: python, text-mining, vector-space-models, lsi

I build a classifier of documents using the vector representation of each document in the training set (i.e a row in the Document-Term Matrix). Now I need to test the model on the test data. But how can I represent a new document with the Document-Term Matrix since some terms might not be included in training data?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to treat all out-of-vocabulary terms as a specific term in your matrix (i.e. "OOV").

So for instance, if my training data contains 3 words: "I", "like", "cake", my document-term matrix would contain 4 items, "I", "like", "cake", and "OOV".

Comment: Is there a way to automate this procedure?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use scikit-learn's [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), words that appear in the test dataset but not in the training dataset are automatically ignored.

The `fit_transform` method is called on training data creating the document-term matrix. The `transform` only method is called on the test data which transforms those documents to document-term matrix created in training, automatically dropping any new terms.